# How to deal with Cron API call in Flask?

Tags: flask

I am using Python Flask to build my application. But recently I am caught up with an error when I request the API for time consuming data, just some physical server hardware data, but may take more than 10s sometimes.

```
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 657, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 716, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
socket.error: [Errno 10053]
```

I figured it out that my http request client will disconnect with a timeout of 5s. As I delete the timeout parameter, this error no longer exists. In fact the API is called every 5s, so if the task itself takes longer than 5s, the later requests will stuck and stuck. My question is it possible to config flask to abort incoming requests while processing the same request? Or any advice on this type is appreciating. TIA.  :)

Comment: Try [Celery Based Background Tasks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/)

Comment: Thanks stamaimer. But my problem is that to process the incomming request will take more than 5s.